# How to decrypt django pbkdf2_sha256 algorthim password?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, sha, pbkdf2

I need user_password plaintext using Django. I tried many ways to get plaintext in user_password. but It's not working. So, I analyzed how the Django user password is generated. it's using the make_password method in the Django core model. In this method generating the hashed code using( pbkdf2_sha256) algorthm. If any possible to decrypt the password.

Example:
pbkdf2_sha256$150000$O9hNDLwzBc7r$RzJPG76Vki36xEflUPKn37jYI3xRbbf6MTPrWbjFrgQ=

Comment: why would you want to decrypt the password?

Comment: I need to check any password having whitespace or not. That purpose only I need to decrypt.

Comment: if you want to disallow password having whitespaces. You should disallow it when creating a User. Hash is a one-way encryption, so no you can't check it.

Comment: Is any another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already seen, Django uses hashing method like SHA256 in this case. Hashing mechanisms basically use lossy compression method, so there is no way to decrypt hashed messages as they are irreversible. Because it is not encryption and there is no backward method like decryption. It is safe to store password in the hashed form, as only creator of the password should know the original password and the backend system just compares the hashes.

This is normal situation for most backend frameworks. Because this is made for security reasons so far. Passwords are hashed and saved in the database so that even if the malicious user gets access to the database, he can't find usefull information there or it will be really hard to crack the hashes with some huge words dictionary.